# How to add a second authentication handler to CAS after x509Check?

Tags: java, spring-webflow, cas

I would like to configure CAS (3.5.0) to execute a second AuthenticationHandler after x509Check is successful. This Handler will send `clientCert.getSubjectDN().getName()` to a webservice and lookup if the user can log in.

It seems like the correct way to accomplish this is through *login-webflow.xml*. First perform the x509Check and then, when successful, direct the request to a second action which verifies permission using the X509CertificateCredentials. I will accept any approach though.